# C++ CString equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, cstring

What is the `C#` equivalent for MFC's `CString`?

Comment: `CString` is an MFC class which is not part of standard C++. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably `System.String`.  But in an effort to provide more useful information:

- `System.String` instances are immutable.  Concatenation/substring/etc actually create new string objects, so using a string instance as a buffer for building up output is a really bad idea, in case you were going to do that.  Think of `System.String` as a `const CString`.
- `System.Text.StringBuilder` is used to build up and manipulate string content.  It has a `.ToString()` method you can call to turn its contents into a proper string.
- You can use `char[]` as a sort of string builder alternative, if you know exactly how long a generated string will turn out to be, but even so you can use `new StringBuilder(length)` to specify a default initial capacity.  You can then use the relevant append methods without having to keep around an index variable.  (`StringBuilder` does that for you.)

As Billy mentioned in the other answer to this question, C# has a keyword `string` that is essentially a shortcut to the `System.String` type.  Both are completely equivalent, though most coders will LART you if you use the uppercase form.

Comment: +1 -- though I think you mean StringBuilder rather than StringBuffer.

Comment: `"most coders will LART you if you use the uppercase form"` what is LART btw?

Comment: LART can be defined as "to hit over the head with a clue-by-four."

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx), and see if it helps.

Comment: Note that this has additional support in the language in the form of the (lowercase) `string`.

Answer (score 2):

You know, `CString` ain't exactly a shining example of OO design done right. MS kept adding member functions to it until it resembled a Swiss army knife... while still missing impotant functions.

Anything you can do with a CString can be better done with the immutable 'System.String` and a number of support classes.